# Navision G/L entry date and time

Tags: navision

I do not know Nav data model. I need to perform an analysis on ledger entry times. I found tables dbo.[COMPANY_NAME$G_L Entry], but there is no indication of time in any datetime fields. E.g. [Posting Date] is '26.07.2018 00:00:00'.

Please find below the table def.

```
[timestamp] timestamp
[Entry No_] int
[G_L Account No_]   varchar(20)
[Posting Date]  datetime
[Document Type] int
[Document No_]  varchar(20)
[Description]   varchar(50)
[Bal_ Account No_]  varchar(20)
[Amount]    decimal(38, 20)
[Global Dimension 1 Code]   varchar(20)
[Global Dimension 2 Code]   varchar(20)
[User ID]   varchar(20)
[Source Code]   varchar(10)
[System-Created Entry]  tinyint
[Prior-Year Entry]  tinyint
[Job No_]   varchar(20)
[Quantity]  decimal(38, 20)
[VAT Amount]    decimal(38, 20)
[Business Unit Code]    varchar(10)
[Journal Batch Name]    varchar(10)
[Reason Code]   varchar(10)
[Gen_ Posting Type] int
[Gen_ Bus_ Posting Group]   varchar(10)
[Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group]  varchar(10)
[Bal_ Account Type] int
[Transaction No_]   int
[Debit Amount]  decimal(38, 20)
[Credit Amount] decimal(38, 20)
[Document Date] datetime
[External Document No_] varchar(20)
[Source Type]   int
[Source No_]    varchar(20)
[No_ Series]    varchar(10)
[Tax Area Code] varchar(20)
[Tax Liable]    tinyint
[Tax Group Code]    varchar(10)
[Use Tax]   tinyint
[VAT Bus_ Posting Group]    varchar(10)
[VAT Prod_ Posting Group]   varchar(10)
[Additional-Currency Amount]    decimal(38, 20)
[Add_-Currency Debit Amount]    decimal(38, 20)
[Add_-Currency Credit Amount]   decimal(38, 20)
[Close Income Statement Dim_ ID]    int
[IC Partner Code]   varchar(20)
[Reversed]  tinyint
[Reversed by Entry No_] int
[Reversed Entry No_]    int
[Prod_ Order No_]   varchar(20)
[FA Entry Type] int
[FA Entry No_]  int
[Applies-to ID] varchar(20)
[Letter]    varchar(3)
[Letter Date]   datetime
[Transaction Currency]  varchar(10)
[Transaction Amount (FCY)]  decimal(38, 20)
[Transaction Curr_ Factor]  decimal(38, 20)
[Amount (FCY)]  decimal(38, 20)
[Cost Entry No_]    int
```

So, the questions are:

- Is [G_L Entry] the right table?
- Is there a way to find datetime fields?
- Is the missing time part in datetime columns a result of client's customizing?

Many thanks for consideration.

Answer (score 0):

- Is [G_L Entry] the right table?

It depends on what you need to analyze. GL is the general ledger. It shows money movement between GL accounts. Is you want item movement see Item Ledger Entry. For costs see Value Entry.

- Is there a way to find datetime fields?

Probably not if they are not added by customization. For Nav time is not relevant in most cases. You probably don’t care when you sold something during the day, in the morning or in the evening. This is ERP, not stock market. Starting balance, ending balance, that is all you need.

- Is the missing time part in datetime columns a result of client's customizing?

No. If datetime field contains only date part then it means that in Nav this is just date field. Nav has three separate types: date, time and datetime. All of them are datetime on sql. Sometimes date might have time part as 23:59:59 this is still a date type in Nav but the value is called closing date.

Comment: Thanks Max for the clarification. That's also what I found from the data. There is just no indication of Time in Datetime column(s).